# Jenkins, start build machine from item

Tags: jenkins, proxmox

I have Proxmox and Jenkins. I need to start a virtual machine on Proxmox (build slave) from a job in Jenkins.

I have a script that automatically creates and starts a VM on Proxmox and adds this VM as Jenkins slave. How to run this script from an item on Jenkins?

Comment: Can you clarify where does this script adds the VM?

Comment: Script add VM on proxmox. I run it on proxmox machine from ssh.

Comment: So basically you need to know how can a Jenkins job run your script (to create a VM) ?

Comment: Jenkins can run this script and VM will be create on proxmox(from shell using **ssh root@proxmox-ip -C "script"**. But I do not know how to run the script from the item, because item requires that the build-agent have already been launched.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there exists a Jenkins plugin that provides Proxmox integration.

You can have a look at https://plugins.jenkins.io/proxmox/